# How to pass HTTP request to Web-Service

Tags: ajax, web-services, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

From my portlet JSP, I am trying to make a Ajax call to web-service.
My aim is to pass HTTP request object as a parameter to web-service method.
Please suggest.

Comment: You should really be adding some example code. Your question is to abstract, that anybody could give you a proper proposal on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting to rethink your problem. A servlet request object does not make any sense as parameter for a web service call. Those are two totally different frameworks. A servlet request only makes sense within the processing of a servlet and is defined within that context.

You are probably interested in some data from that object, e.g. attributes or some data from the session. Use exactly that data as parameters and forget about your original plans

Comment: Well explained @Olaf Kock.